# Archive Error on Xcode 15 (unable to read the file at '......)

Tags: ios, xcode

I got this error when archiving with Xcode 15.0 ❌

```
unable to read the file at '/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-evdaaakoxjwwlberzguzentcxrnd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Framework/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/FrameworkName.framework/FrameworkName'
```

[Build error in multiplatform build script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxc33.png)

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jl2jx.png)

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbZFc.png)

I can run to Simulator and Device in Xcode 15.0. ✅
I can run to Simulator, Device, and Archive in Xcode 14.2. ✅

The problem only appear when archiving with Xcode 15.

**Additional Info:**

- No cocoapods
- Objc Project

Here's the **Multiplatform Build** script in the framework

```
set -e

# If we're already inside this script then die
if [ -n "$RW_MULTIPLATFORM_BUILD_IN_PROGRESS" ]; then
exit 0
fi
export RW_MULTIPLATFORM_BUILD_IN_PROGRESS=1

RW_FRAMEWORK_NAME=${PROJECT_NAME}
RW_INPUT_STATIC_LIB="lib${PROJECT_NAME}.a"
RW_FRAMEWORK_LOCATION="${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${RW_FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"

function build_static_library {
    # Will rebuild the static library as specified
    #     build_static_library sdk
    xcrun xcodebuild -project "${PROJECT_FILE_PATH}" \
    -target "${PROJECT_NAME}" \
    -configuration "${CONFIGURATION}" \
    -sdk "${1}" \
    ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO \
    BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" \
    OBJROOT="${OBJROOT}/DependentBuilds" \
    BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" \
    SYMROOT="${SYMROOT}" $ACTION
}

function make_fat_library {
    # Will smash 2 static libs together
    #     make_fat_library in1 in2 out
    xcrun lipo -create "${1}" "${2}" -output "${3}"
}

# Extract the platform (iphoneos/iphonesimulator) from the SDK name
if [[ "$SDK_NAME" =~ ([A-Za-z]+) ]]; then
RW_SDK_PLATFORM=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
else
echo "Could not find platform name from SDK_NAME: $SDK_NAME"
exit 1
fi

# Extract the version from the SDK
if [[ "$SDK_NAME" =~ ([0-9]+.*$) ]]; then
RW_SDK_VERSION=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
else
echo "Could not find sdk version from SDK_NAME: $SDK_NAME"
exit 1
fi

# Determine the other platform
if [ "$RW_SDK_PLATFORM" == "iphoneos" ]; then
RW_OTHER_PLATFORM=iphonesimulator
else
RW_OTHER_PLATFORM=iphoneos
fi

# Find the build directory
if [[ "$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR" =~ (.*)$RW_SDK_PLATFORM$ ]]; then
RW_OTHER_BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${RW_OTHER_PLATFORM}"
else
echo "Could not find other platform build directory."
exit 1
fi


# Build the other platform.
build_static_library "${RW_OTHER_PLATFORM}${RW_SDK_VERSION}"

# If we're currently building for iphonesimulator, then need to rebuild
#   to ensure that we get both i386 and x86_64
if [ "$RW_SDK_PLATFORM" == "iphonesimulator" ]; then
build_static_library "${SDK_NAME}"
fi

# Join the 2 static libs into 1 and push into the .framework
#make_fat_library "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${RW_INPUT_STATIC_LIB}" \
#"${RW_OTHER_BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${RW_INPUT_STATIC_LIB}" \
#"${RW_FRAMEWORK_LOCATION}/Versions/A/${RW_FRAMEWORK_NAME}"


# Ensure that the framework is present in both platorm's build directories
#cp -a "${RW_FRAMEWORK_LOCATION}/Versions/A/${RW_FRAMEWORK_NAME}" \
#"${RW_OTHER_BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${RW_FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework/Versions/A/${RW_FRAMEWORK_NAME}"

# Generate framework for each platform
cp -a "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${RW_INPUT_STATIC_LIB}" \
"${RW_FRAMEWORK_LOCATION}/Versions/A/${RW_FRAMEWORK_NAME}"
cp -a "${RW_OTHER_BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${RW_INPUT_STATIC_LIB}" \
"${RW_OTHER_BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${RW_FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework/Versions/A/${RW_FRAMEWORK_NAME}"

# Combine generated frameworks into xcframework
rm -rf "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${RW_FRAMEWORK_NAME}.xcframework"
xcodebuild -create-xcframework -framework "${RW_FRAMEWORK_LOCATION}" -framework "${RW_OTHER_BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${RW_FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework" -output "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${RW_FRAMEWORK_NAME}.xcframework"

# Copy the framework to the project's directory
ditto "${RW_FRAMEWORK_LOCATION}" "${SRCROOT}/${RW_FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"
ditto "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${RW_FRAMEWORK_NAME}.xcframework" "${SRCROOT}/${RW_FRAMEWORK_NAME}.xcframework"

# Copy the resources bundle to the project's directory
rm -rf "${SRCROOT}/${RW_FRAMEWORK_NAME}.bundle"
ditto "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${RW_FRAMEWORK_NAME}.bundle" \
"${SRCROOT}/${RW_FRAMEWORK_NAME}.bundle"
```

Here's the full build/error log:
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/zmkhtr/108a63f64c8c6f9877eb5a4fcd4949e8/raw/25a2d028bf1b7f43536af3344d97307455b4c0a3/archiveerror.log

I try many solution I can find, but still can't make it success.

Like clear derived data, modifying build script, build setting, etc.